# Swift 3 LPCM Audio Recorder | Error: kAudioFileInvalidPacketOffsetError

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, audiotoolbox, recorder

The below recorder works only the first time, if you tried recording a second time it gives the error 'kAudioFileInvalidPacketOffsetError' when trying to AudioFileWritePackets.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you in advance

[Repository located here](https://github.com/LuAndreCast/iOS_AudioRecordersAndPlayers/tree/master/recorder_LPCM)

**Recorder**

```
import UIKit
import CoreAudio
import AudioToolbox


class SpeechRecorder: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SpeechRecorder()

    // MARK:- properties
    @objc enum Status: Int {
        case ready
        case busy
        case error
    }

    internal struct RecordState {
        var format: AudioStreamBasicDescription
        var queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef?>
        var buffers: [AudioQueueBufferRef?]
        var file: AudioFileID?
        var currentPacket: Int64
        var recording: Bool
    };

    private var recordState: RecordState?

    var format: AudioFormatID {
        get { return recordState!.format.mFormatID }
        set {  recordState!.format.mFormatID = newValue }
    }

    var sampleRate: Float64 {
        get { return recordState!.format.mSampleRate }
        set {  recordState!.format.mSampleRate = newValue  }
    }

    var formatFlags: AudioFormatFlags {
        get {  return recordState!.format.mFormatFlags }
        set {   recordState!.format.mFormatFlags = newValue  }
    }

    var channelsPerFrame: UInt32 {
        get {   return recordState!.format.mChannelsPerFrame }
        set {   recordState!.format.mChannelsPerFrame = newValue }
    }

    var bitsPerChannel: UInt32 {
        get {   return recordState!.format.mBitsPerChannel }
        set {   recordState!.format.mBitsPerChannel = newValue  }
    }

    var framesPerPacket: UInt32 {
        get {  return recordState!.format.mFramesPerPacket }
        set {   recordState!.format.mFramesPerPacket = newValue }
    }

    var bytesPerFrame: UInt32 {
        get {  return recordState!.format.mBytesPerFrame }
        set {   recordState!.format.mBytesPerFrame = newValue }
    }

    var bytesPerPacket: UInt32 {
        get { return recordState!.format.mBytesPerPacket  }
        set {  recordState!.format.mBytesPerPacket = newValue }
    }

    //MARK: - Handlers
    public var handler: ((Status) -> Void)?

    // MARK:- Init
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.recordState = RecordState(format: AudioStreamBasicDescription(),
                                       queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef?>.allocate(capacity: 1),
                                       buffers: [AudioQueueBufferRef?](repeating: nil, count: 1),
                                       file: nil,
                                       currentPacket: 0,
                                       recording: false)
    }//eom



    // MARK:- OutputFile
    func setOutputFile(path: String)
    {
        setOutputFile(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    }

    func setOutputFile(url: URL)
    {
        AudioFileCreateWithURL(url as CFURL,
                               kAudioFileWAVEType,
                               &recordState!.format,
                               AudioFileFlags.dontPageAlignAudioData.union(.eraseFile),
                               &recordState!.file)
    }

    // MARK:- Start / Stop Recording
    func start()
    {
        handler?(.busy)

        let inputAudioQueue: AudioQueueInputCallback =
            { (userData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                audioQueue: AudioQueueRef,
                bufferQueue: AudioQueueBufferRef,
                startTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                packets: UInt32,
                packetDescription: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) in

                let internalRSP = unsafeBitCast(userData, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<RecordState>.self)
                if packets > 0
                {
                    var packetsReceived = packets
                    let outputStream:OSStatus = AudioFileWritePackets(internalRSP.pointee.file!,
                                                                      false,
                                                                      bufferQueue.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize,
                                                                      packetDescription,
                                                                      internalRSP.pointee.currentPacket,
                                                                      &packetsReceived,
                                                                      bufferQueue.pointee.mAudioData)
                    if outputStream != 0
                    {
                        // This is where the error occurs when recording after the first time
                        //<----DEBUG
                        switch outputStream
                        {
                            case kAudioFilePermissionsError:
                                print("kAudioFilePermissionsError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileNotOptimizedError:
                                print("kAudioFileNotOptimizedError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileInvalidChunkError:
                                print("kAudioFileInvalidChunkError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileDoesNotAllow64BitDataSizeError:
                               print("kAudioFileDoesNotAllow64BitDataSizeError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileInvalidPacketOffsetError:
                                print("kAudioFileInvalidPacketOffsetError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileInvalidFileError:
                                print("kAudioFileInvalidFileError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileOperationNotSupportedError:
                                print("kAudioFileOperationNotSupportedError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileNotOpenError:
                                print("kAudioFileNotOpenError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileEndOfFileError:
                                print("kAudioFileEndOfFileError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFilePositionError:
                                print("kAudioFilePositionError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileFileNotFoundError:
                                print("kAudioFileFileNotFoundError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileUnspecifiedError:
                                print("kAudioFileUnspecifiedError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileUnsupportedFileTypeError:
                                print("kAudioFileUnsupportedFileTypeError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError:
                                print("kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileUnsupportedPropertyError:
                                print("kAudioFileUnsupportedPropertyError")
                                break
                            case kAudioFileBadPropertySizeError:
                                print("kAudioFileBadPropertySizeError")
                                break
                            default:
                                print("unknown error")
                                break
                        }
                        //<----DEBUG
                    }
                    internalRSP.pointee.currentPacket += Int64(packetsReceived)
                }

                if internalRSP.pointee.recording
                {
                    let outputStream:OSStatus = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueue, bufferQueue, 0, nil)
                    if outputStream != 0
                    {
                     // This is where the error occurs when recording after the first time
                    //<----DEBUG
                    switch outputStream
                    {
                        case kAudioFilePermissionsError:
                            print("kAudioFilePermissionsError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileNotOptimizedError:
                            print("kAudioFileNotOptimizedError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileInvalidChunkError:
                            print("kAudioFileInvalidChunkError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileDoesNotAllow64BitDataSizeError:
                            print("kAudioFileDoesNotAllow64BitDataSizeError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileInvalidPacketOffsetError:
                            print("kAudioFileInvalidPacketOffsetError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileInvalidFileError:
                            print("kAudioFileInvalidFileError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileOperationNotSupportedError:
                            print("kAudioFileOperationNotSupportedError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileNotOpenError:
                            print("kAudioFileNotOpenError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileEndOfFileError:
                            print("kAudioFileEndOfFileError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFilePositionError:
                            print("kAudioFilePositionError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileFileNotFoundError:
                            print("kAudioFileFileNotFoundError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileUnspecifiedError:
                            print("kAudioFileUnspecifiedError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileUnsupportedFileTypeError:
                            print("kAudioFileUnsupportedFileTypeError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError:
                            print("kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileUnsupportedPropertyError:
                            print("kAudioFileUnsupportedPropertyError")
                            break
                        case kAudioFileBadPropertySizeError:
                            print("kAudioFileBadPropertySizeError")
                            break
                        default:
                            print("unknown error")
                            break
                    }
                    //<----DEBUG
                }
            }
    }

    let queueResults = AudioQueueNewInput(&recordState!.format, inputAudioQueue, &recordState, nil, nil, 0, recordState!.queue)
    if queueResults == 0
    {
        let bufferByteSize: Int = calculate(format: recordState!.format, seconds: 0.5)
        for index in (0..<recordState!.buffers.count)
        {
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(recordState!.queue.pointee!, UInt32(bufferByteSize), &recordState!.buffers[index])
            AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(recordState!.queue.pointee!, recordState!.buffers[index]!, 0, nil)
        }

        AudioQueueStart(recordState!.queue.pointee!, nil)
        recordState?.recording = true
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error setting audio input.")
        handler?(.error)
    }
}//eom

func stop()
{
    recordState?.recording = false
    if let recordingState: RecordState = recordState
    {
        AudioQueueStop(recordingState.queue.pointee!, true)
        AudioQueueDispose(recordingState.queue.pointee!, true)
        AudioFileClose(recordingState.file!)

        handler?(.ready)
    }
}//eom

// MARK:- Helper methods
func calculate(format: AudioStreamBasicDescription, seconds: Double) -> Int
{
    let framesRequiredForBufferTime = Int(ceil(seconds * format.mSampleRate))
    if framesRequiredForBufferTime > 0

    {
        return (framesRequiredForBufferTime * Int(format.mBytesPerFrame))
    }
    else
    {
        var maximumPacketSize = UInt32(0)
        if format.mBytesPerPacket > 0
        {
            maximumPacketSize = format.mBytesPerPacket
        }
        else
        {
            audioQueueProperty(propertyId: kAudioQueueProperty_MaximumOutputPacketSize, value: &maximumPacketSize)
        }

        var packets = 0
        if format.mFramesPerPacket > 0
        {
            packets = (framesRequiredForBufferTime / Int(format.mFramesPerPacket))
        } else
        {
            packets = framesRequiredForBufferTime
        }

        if packets == 0
        {
            packets = 1
        }

        return (packets * Int(maximumPacketSize))
    }
}//eom

func audioQueueProperty<T>(propertyId: AudioQueuePropertyID, value: inout T)
{
    let propertySize = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    propertySize.pointee = UInt32(MemoryLayout<T>.size)

    let queueResults = AudioQueueGetProperty(recordState!.queue.pointee!, propertyId, &value, propertySize)
    propertySize.deallocate(capacity: 1)

    if queueResults != 0 {
        print("Unable to get audio queue property.")
    }
    }//eom
  }
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties
    var recorder:SpeechRecorder?

    @IBOutlet weak var startStopRecordingButton: UIButton!



    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       //having same recorder gives error
       recorder = SpeechRecorder()
    }


    //MARK: - Start / End Recording

    func startRecording()
    {
        //alloc/init recorder everytime we start recording gives no error
        //recorder = SpeechRecorder()


        //settings
        recorder?.format = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
        recorder?.sampleRate = 16000;
        recorder?.channelsPerFrame = 1
        recorder?.bitsPerChannel = 16
        recorder?.framesPerPacket = 1
        recorder?.bytesPerFrame = ((recorder!.channelsPerFrame * recorder!.bitsPerChannel) / 8)
        recorder?.bytesPerPacket = recorder!.bytesPerFrame * recorder!.framesPerPacket
        recorder?.formatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked

        //outputfile
        let outputfilePath:String = MyFileManager().createTempFilePathWithUniqueName("recorderAudio", andExtension: "wav")
        print("temp filepath: ", outputfilePath)
        recorder?.setOutputFile(path: outputfilePath)


        //handler
        recorder?.handler = { [weak self] status in
            switch status
            {
                case .busy:
                    print("started Recording\n\n")
                    break
                case .ready:
                    print("finish recorder, ready to start recording\n\n")
                    break
                case .error:
                    print("error occur with recorder\n\n")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self?.startStopRecordingButton.isSelected = false
                        self?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    }

                    break
                }
        }//


        recorder?.start()
    }//eom


    func stopRecording()
    {
      recorder?.stop()
    }//eom

    //MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func startStopRecording()
    {
        if startStopRecordingButton.isSelected
        {
            startStopRecordingButton.isSelected = false
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            startStopRecordingButton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: UIControlState.normal)

            self.stopRecording()
        }
        else
        {
            startStopRecordingButton.isSelected = true
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            startStopRecordingButton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: UIControlState.normal)

            self.startRecording()
        }
    }//eom



    //MARK: - Memory
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**FileManager (Creates Temp filepath)**

```
import Foundation

@objc class MyFileManager:NSObject
{
     private let unique_debug = true
     private var _temporyDirectory:String = ""

    //MARK: - Properties
    var directory:String {
        return _temporyDirectory
    }

    //MARK: - Init
    override init() {
        super.init()

        _temporyDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    }//eom

    func createHomeDirFileUniqueWithName(_ myFileName:String, andExtension fileExtension:String)->URL
    {
        //filename
        let time:Date = Date.init()
        let dateformatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter .dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-hh-mm-ss-a"
        let tempDate:String = dateformatter .string(from: time)
        let tempFileName = "\(myFileName)-\(tempDate).\(fileExtension)"

        //directory
        var documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

        documentsDirectory.appendPathComponent(tempFileName)

        if unique_debug {  print("\(documentsDirectory)") }

        return documentsDirectory
    }//eom

    //MARK: - Names
    func createGlobalUniqueFileName(_ myFileName:String)->String
    {
        let guid = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let uniqueFileName = ("\(myFileName)_\(guid)")

        if unique_debug {  print("\(uniqueFileName)") }

        return uniqueFileName
    }//eom

    func createUniqueNameWithFilename(_ myFileName:String, andExtension fileExtension:String)->String
    {
        //filename
        let time:Date = Date.init()
        let dateformatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter .dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-hh-mm-ss-a"
        let currentDateString = dateformatter .string(from: time)

        let finalName = myFileName + currentDateString + "." + fileExtension

        if unique_debug {  print("\(finalName)") }

        return finalName
    }//eom

    //MARK: - Paths
    func createTempFilePathWithUniqueName(_ myFileName:String, andExtension fileExtension:String)->String
    {
        let tempFileName = self.createUniqueNameWithFilename(myFileName, andExtension: fileExtension)

        let tempFile = _temporyDirectory + tempFileName

        if unique_debug {  print("\(tempFile)") }

        return tempFile
    }//eom

    //MARK: - Helpers
    func enumerateDirectory(directory:String)
    {
        do
        {
            let filesInDir:[String] = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directory)
            for currFile in filesInDir {
                print(currFile)
            }//eofl
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }//eom

    func doesFileExistInDirectory(filename:String) -> Bool {
        do
        {
            let filesInDir:[String] = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: _temporyDirectory)
            for currFile in filesInDir
            {
                print(currFile)
                if currFile == filename {
                    return true
                }
            }//eofl
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        return false
    }//eom

}//eoc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting your `currentPacket` count to zero, so on subsequent recordings, you're asking `AudioFileWritePackets` to start writing to its new file at a nonzero starting packet, which it refuses to do.

The correct solution is (probably) to re-create `RecordState` each time you start a recording, although hackily setting

```
recordState!.currentPacket = 0
```

before calling `AudioQueueNewInput` seems to work too.

Comment: Thanks the below command worked perfectly

                        recordState!.currentPacket = 0

Comment: [How would recording from ViewController and Model be different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595382/recording-from-viewcontroller-vs-a-model-class)   getting a diff nsdata when recording from model